# Reduce this to a simple lambda

Tags: kotlin

I would like to simplify this code by reducing it to just a lambda. The interface has only one function. I'm not sure how to replace the override part of the code with just a lambda expression:

```
interface ITextWatcher {
    fun onTextChanged(text: String) {

    }
}

val textChangeHandler = object: ITextWatcher {
    override fun onTextChanged(text: String) 
         var t = text
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something like this:

```
val textChangeHandler = object: ITextWatcher {text ->

}
```

But that won't compile.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is `val textChangeHandler = ITextWatcher {text -> ... }`, but it doesn't work for interfaces declared in Kotlin, only for Java ones (at least for now).

Use `(String) -> Unit` directly instead. Or declare a function to convert one to another:

```
inline fun ITextWatcher(crossinline f: (String) -> Unit) = object : ITextWatcher {
    override fun onTextChanged(text: String) {
         f(text)
    }
}

val textChangeHandler = ITextWatcher {text -> ... }
```

if you want.